# How to define/format date and time in python

Tags: python, sorting, date, pandas, time

My cvs file has **Date** and **time** columns. after I import csv file to python, the data frame looks like:

```
name      date       time      price    ....
vod     01-Nov-13   00:22.9     99
vod     01-Nov-13   00:23.0     98
vod     02-Nov-13   00:22.9     96
vod     02-Nov-13   00:24.1     92
...      ....        ....       ...
vod     31-Dec-13   00:22.9     99
```

first of all, there **something wrong with time column**. This is trading data, so the time should be from **7:00 to 16:30**. It seems python misread the time format.

However,after I sorted the data by date. The data was like

```
name      date         ....
vod     01-Nov-13       
vod     01-Dec-13       
vod     02-Nov-13     
vod     02-Dec-13    
vod     03-Nov-13 
vod     03-Dec-13
```

again, some wrong with date format. The time shouldn't be in this order...

I just have one question how to **define/format date and time** in python(pandas), so that I can sort data in order.

Comment: What does your CSV file look like before importing into Python?

Comment: Could you provide an example how the raw data in your csv file looks? The first couple of lines for example? That would make it easier to understand what goes wrong here

Comment: You can parse strings into dates and format dates into strings with the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html).

Comment: @chris-sc The csv file is exactly the same as python output. Do I have to manually change format on csv ?

Comment: @PeterGibson The csv file is exactly the same as python output. Do I have to manually change format on csv ?

Comment: Assuming your dataframe is `df`, can you share the output of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: If the csv file is the same as the python output, what time format is this? (00:22.9 in your example) - is this really exactly what is written in your csv file?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

> from Python datetime module datetime object 
>   datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])

Comment: @vignesh, thanks, could you tell me where to put this code ?

Comment: @TristanSun after you load to Python CSV file combine data from columns date and time to datetime object. In date column you have date, month (have to be integer, it may be changed with dict) and year (13 have to be replaced with 2013) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, while we don't know how your time column in the csv looks like, I'll assume it is in hh:mm:ss format:

```
name, date, time, price
vod, 01-Nov-13, 07:40:00, 99
vod, 01-Nov-13, 07:34:50, 95
```

Have a look at the following minimal example. It uses the proposed csv input, combines the date and time column into one datetime object. With the column as dtype datetime64[ns], pandas can sort the data easily.

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                         
import pandas as pd                                                              

# just write a short example.csv to test this.                                                                       
with open('example.csv', 'w') as f:                                              
    f.write('name, date, time, price\n')                                         
    f.write('vod, 01-Nov-13, 07:40:00, 99\nvod, 01-Nov-13, 07:34:50, 95')                     

# read the csv and use the parse_dates option of pd.read_csv to
# format and combine the date and time columns                                                                        
pdf = pd.read_csv('example.csv', parse_dates=[[1, 2]])                            

# for conveniency: rename the column to datetime                         
pdf.rename(columns={' date_ time': 'datetime'}, inplace=True)

# Sort the dataframe according to the datetime column                 
pdf.sort(columns='datetime', inplace=True)
```

For more details on the options of parse_dates have a look at the doc:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

If the time format in your csv is something parse_dates can't handle, you could use the `converters` option in `pd.read_csv` - but for this we need to know how your raw data actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

So you have two question.

First, time column is wrong. By the comment you said that the csv file is exactly what you post. Which means the data you get are something like `00:22.9`, but you think it's wrong. Since we don't have a corresponding data that could map to the actually time, so you might need to check that if the time `00:22.9` is ***elapsed time*** or whatever(`00:22.9` might represent `07:22.9`?).

Second, the date string sort problem. Here I transform all the data into a dict list as below: (the data is built by myself)

```
data =
[{'date': '01-Nov-13', 'name': 'vod', 'price': '98', 'time': '00:23.0'},
{'date': '01-Jan-13', 'name': 'vod', 'price': '91', 'time': '00:23.0'},
{'date': '02-Nov-13', 'name': 'vod', 'price': '96', 'time': '00:22.0'},
{'date': '01-Dec-13', 'name': 'vod', 'price': '101', 'time': '00:23.0'}]
```

then with the `sorted` function and `datetime` module (remember the `sorted` function change the `data` it self)

```
from datetime import datetime
sorted(data, key=lambda each_dict: datetime.strptime(each_dict['date'], '%d-%b-%y'))
```

the `%d-%b-%y` is the mask corresponding to `01-Nov-13` (day-month-year), check [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for other masks.

- **Edit**: if you just want to parse the date data, just simply call:

  ```
  datetime.strptime(<date_input>, '%d-%b-%y')
  ```

  this will return a datetime object like:

  ```
  datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 1, 0, 0)
  ```

The whole sorted data is:

```
[{'date': '01-Jan-13', 'name': 'vod', 'price': '91', 'time': '00:23.0'},
{'date': '01-Nov-13', 'name': 'vod', 'price': '98', 'time': '00:23.0'},
{'date': '02-Nov-13', 'name': 'vod', 'price': '96', 'time': '00:22.0'},
{'date': '01-Dec-13', 'name': 'vod', 'price': '101', 'time': '00:23.0'}]
```

The only problem is, it might take some time/memory if you got lots of data set to sort

Comment: Glad to help, would be better if you mark either one of 3 answers as _Answer_ to help me and other ppl :).